# Python Django official tutorial "Polls", beginner gets frustrating errors

Tags: python, django, compiler-errors, virtualenv

I am trying to follow through the Python Django Tutorial from the official site.

However I find it hard to follow. I did everything as written but I got the following error"

[ERROR screen caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8pce.jpg)

It sounds like something is wrong with the ENV, but I am not so sure why.
Also at the last line of error it said "include is not defined"...

Comment: from django.conf.urls import include,

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your environment. The error is what you said: you haven't defined or imported "include" in your urls.py. The tutorial shows you what to do, you have to follow it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the line `from django.conf.urls import include, url`.